# What the font: the letter i used in Apple's information button

Tags: font

I am wondering what typeface this is:

[image]

Comment: Some people built special services for just this type of thing: http://www.whatfontis.com/

Comment: @cksum Cool site! Too bad it requires two letters though.

Comment: @cksum already tried whatthefont, they couldn't id it, neither could yours. :(

Comment: @martnu According character table on my mac, best choices are: Cambria Math, STIXGeneral, STIXGeneral. But they are not same. It's not full answer, but may be it's point where to look for

Comment: It's not unlikely this icon did not use any particular font, but was designed as a vector shape.

Comment: @martnu have you asked your question in font-specific forums?

Comment: Similar on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/345037/is-there-a-program-that-can-scan-an-image-and-tell-you-what-font-type-its-using

Comment: Where is that icon file stored? I'd like to pixel peep at retina resolutions if possible. My guess it that it's designed by hand and not just a font. See [this](http://www.firewheeldesign.com/sparkplug/2006/April/icon_design_bitmap_vs_vector.php) and [that](http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/6840184364/hand-pixelated) for what I mean hand drawn.

Answer (score 8):

Hoefler Text Bold Italic

http://www.typography.com/fonts/font_styles.php?productLineID=100010

[image]

It was [designed for Apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoefler_Text):

> Hoefler Text is a contemporary serif Antiqua font that was designed
>   for Apple Computer to demonstrate advanced type technologies. Hoefler
>   Text was created to allow the composition of complex typography; as
>   such it takes cues from a range of classic fonts, such as Garamond and
>   Janson. Designed by Jonathan Hoefler in 1991, a version of Hoefler
>   Text has been included with every version of Mac OS since System 7.5.

Answer (score 2):

Baskerville SemiBold italic is pretty close

Comment: I was going to say Garmond Premier Bold Italic Subhead, but yours is closer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Fonts. It may Matches I think.
**"Monotype Corsiva", 
"Mutter Krause Hal", "Sudbury Book-Italic"**

Comment: And these fonts are available from where?

Comment: Please visit this site. http://www.fontspace.com/category/italic?p=2

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! This site is meant to be a collaborative reference for the Apple community, which means answers should be aiming to be detailed, reasoned and useful. in your case, as patrix stated, usefulness suffers from a lack of links. Reasoning and and detail could both be improved by explaining how you conclude these fonts match.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, the "info i" is a *graphic element* buried in the respective app’s resources folder. For example, this "i" is from `/System/Library/CoreServices/` .. `CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/` .. `ToolbarInfo.icns` (path split for readability):

[image]

You can browse resources for any app by selecting `Show package contents` for an Application in Finder (cmd-click), then navigating to the `Contents` folder. Common file types are [icns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image), PNG or PDF.

Answer (score -2):

http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ sais that this picture looks like [BearButte Bold Italic](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/ingrimayne/bearbutte/bear-butte-t-bold-italic/) font

Also you can look at this [quiz](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?362151-How-To-Recognize-A-Font-A-Mini-Guide-To-Successful-Font-Recognition) to find letters from images

Comment: +1 for WTF, but, honestly, BearButte's *i* doesn't look like the *i* on OP's question.

Comment: I see. May be it is not exact font. This glyph can be created by designer, not extracted from font. I haven't seen same i before (I've seen same i without left flourish in Windows system)